# How to read certain char to certain char from file in java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, java.util.scanner, coordinate

I have a text file, which contains positions like this:

[image]

The #p shows the x, y coordinates, so the first * after the #p row is at (6, -1). I would like to read the text file as blocks (one block is from the #p to the next #p row).

```
try {
        File file = new File("filename.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
            if (line.startsWith("#P")){
                Scanner s = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(" ");
                List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (s.hasNext()) {
                    myList.add(s.next());
                }
                for (int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++){
                    System.out.println(myList.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println("xy: "+myList.get(1)+", "+myList.get(2));
            }
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to store the coordinates in a two dimensional array, but there goes my other problem. How can I store etc -1, -1?

Comment: Do you know what the smallest value of a coordinate can be?  If so, you can just offset everything by a positive constant.

Comment: why two dimensional? you want coor[x][y] == true if the point exists? It's impossible since you have negative values

Comment: This is a game of life implementation and my idea is to have two arrays with 0 and 1 values, one for the current state and another to the next state. Thats why i would like to make a two dimensional array from the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't completely solve your problem, but one option here is to use a map to store each block of text, where a *pair* of coordinates is a key, and the text a value.

```
Map<String, String> contentMap = new HashMap<>();
String currKey = null;
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("#P")) {
        // store previous paragraph in the map
        if (currKey != null) {
            contentMap.put(currKey, buffer.toString());
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
        }
        currKey = line.substring(3);
    }
    else {
        buffer.append(line).append("\n");
    }
}
```

Once you have the map in memory, you can either use it as is, or you could iterate and somehow convert it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[][] coords = new byte[X_MAX - X_MIN + 1][Y_MAX - Y_MIN + 1]; //your array with 0 and 1 as you wished

try {
    File file = new File("filename.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    //StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(); //i don't c why you need it here
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        //stringBuffer.append(line);
        //stringBuffer.append("\n");
        if (line.startsWith("#P")){
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            coords[x - X_MIN][y - Y_MIN] = 1;
        }
    bufferedReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indices in Java always start at 0. But that's not really a problem if you know the total ranges of your x and y values (X_MIN <= x < X_MAX and Y_MIN <= y < Y_MAX):

```
coor[X_MAX - X_MIN + 1][Y_MAX - Y_MIN + 1];

...

void setValue( int x, int y, int value ) {
    coor[x - X_MIN][y - Y_MIN] = value;
}

int getValue( int x, int y ) {
    return coor[x + X_MIN][y + Y_MIN];
}
```

A nicer solution would wrap the array into a class, provide range checking and maybe use a different container like `ArrayList<ArrayList<int>>` .